# VB.net Dataset to XML Purchase Order

Tags: xml, vb.net, excel

I've coded a program in VB.net that has allowed me to convert an Excel file to XML using OleDB strings, read it into a Datatable, then into a Dataset, and lastly converted the Dataset to XML, which can be saved into another file.

Now I'm stumped on how can I get the XML to save the elements in a specific way, basically to look like a purchase order?

All of my current code and screenshot of my excel file is below. Any help is appreciated.

How the XML File **Should** Look If My Code Worked:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII" standalone="yes"?>
    <CustomerPurchaseOrder xmlns="http://www.dummysite.com/">
      <CustomerPurchaseOrderFile>
      <FirstName>John</FirstName>
      <LastName>Smith</LastName>
      <OrderDate>2015-12-11</OrderDate>
      <SpecialInstructions>Leave at front door</SpecialInstructions>
      <LineItems>
        <LineItem>
          <ItemDescription>Brown Shirt</ItemDescription>
          <QTY>1</QTY>
          <Price>$12.99</Price>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
          <ItemDescription>Black Shoes Pair</ItemDescription>
          <QTY>1</QTY>
          <Price>$45.89</Price>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
          <ItemDescription>Oranges</ItemDescription>
          <QTY>5</QTY>
          <Price>$8.99</Price>
        </LineItem>
      </LineItems>
      <FirstName>Lisa</FirstName>
      <LastName>Lane</LastName>
      <OrderDate>2016-01-12</OrderDate>
      <SpecialInstructions />
      <LineItems>
        <LineItem>
          <ItemDescription>Wheat Bread Loaf</ItemDescription>
          <QTY>3</QTY>
          <Price>$5.99</Price>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
          <ItemDescription>TV Samsung 40"</ItemDescription>
          <QTY>1</QTY>
          <Price> $539.99</Price>
        </LineItem>
      </LineItems>
      </CustomerPurchaseOrderFile>
    </CustomerPurchaseOrder>
```

What I Currently Get - Not What I Want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<CustomerPurchaseOrder xmlns="http://www.dummysite.com">
  <CustomerPurchaseOrderFile>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <OrderDate>2015-12-11T00:00:00-08:00</OrderDate>
    <SpecialInstructions>Leave at front door</SpecialInstructions>
    <ItemDescription>Brown Shirt</ItemDescription>
    <QTY>1</QTY>
    <Price>12.99</Price>
  </CustomerPurchaseOrderFile>
  <CustomerPurchaseOrderFile>
    <ItemDescription>Black Shoes Pair</ItemDescription>
    <QTY>1</QTY>
    <Price>45.89</Price>
  </CustomerPurchaseOrderFile>
  <CustomerPurchaseOrderFile>
    <ItemDescription>Oranges</ItemDescription>
    <QTY>5</QTY>
    <Price>8.99</Price>
  </CustomerPurchaseOrderFile>
  <CustomerPurchaseOrderFile>
    <FirstName>Lisa</FirstName>
    <LastName>Lane</LastName>
    <OrderDate>2016-01-12T00:00:00-08:00</OrderDate>
    <ItemDescription>Wheat Bread Loaf</ItemDescription>
    <QTY>3</QTY>
    <Price>5.99</Price>
  </CustomerPurchaseOrderFile>
  <CustomerPurchaseOrderFile>
    <ItemDescription>TV Samsung 40"</ItemDescription>
    <QTY>1</QTY>
    <Price>539.99</Price>
  </CustomerPurchaseOrderFile>
</CustomerPurchaseOrder>
```

My VB.Net Code

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    Dim myDS As DataSet
    Dim myDT As DataTable = New DataTable("CustomerPurchaseOrderFile")
    Dim myFilePath As String()

    'Load Excel File Button
    Private Sub loadFileBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loadFileBtn.Click
        'choose excel file
        'file dialog box properties
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls, *.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx"
        OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        saveXMLBtn.Enabled = False
        Dim checkOpenDialog As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Dim myConnection As String, excelConn As OleDbConnection
        Dim myAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
        'import file using OleDB connections into datatable -> dataset -> xml
        Try
            'disable save button if no file is loaded
            If checkOpenDialog = DialogResult.Cancel Then
                saveXMLBtn.Enabled = False
            ElseIf checkOpenDialog = DialogResult.None Then
                saveXMLBtn.Enabled = False
            ElseIf checkOpenDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                myFilePath = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
                myConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + myFilePath(0) + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;"""
                excelConn = New OleDbConnection(myConnection)
                excelConn.Open()
                myAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConn)
                myDT = New DataTable()
                myDS = New DataSet()
                myDS.Tables.Add(myDT)
                myDS.Merge(myDT)
                myDS.DataSetName = "CustomerPurchaseOrder"
                myDS.Namespace = "http://www.dummysite.com"
                myDS.Prefix = ""
                myAdapter.Fill(myDS, "CustomerPurchaseOrderFile")
                myDS.AcceptChanges()
                excelConn.Close()
                'dataset -> string storage
                Dim storeXML As String = myDS.GetXml
                'preview in text box
                xmlPreviewBox.Text = storeXML
            End If
            'save dataset to string
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            If myFilePath IsNot Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Preview of XML File Loaded.")
                saveXMLBtn.Enabled = True
            End If

        End Try
    End Sub
    'Save Converted Excel to XML File
    Private Sub saveXMLBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles saveXMLBtn.Click
        'file dialog box properties
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml"
        SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
        SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        saveXMLBtn.Enabled = False
        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        myFilePath = SaveFileDialog1.FileNames
        Try
            If SaveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
                'myDS.WriteXml(myFilePath, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)
                myDS.WriteXml(myFilePath(0)) 'works and above works the same
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            MsgBox("XML File Saved Successfully.")
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

[My Excel File Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm7fJ.png)

Comment: XML to a DataSet and back is ugly, especially if you have related tables.  I think it'd be easier to simply extract the data from Excel, and then insert into the table(s) and generate the XML file.  At a glance at your generated XML file, you have multiple tables, and like I said, that makes for a mess in XML, in my experience.

Comment: So, you're saying to leave out the dataset? So basically excel -> datatable -> xml .. I can do that, but I'll still be stuck at the step on how to get the XML into the right purchase order-esque format I need. I don't have much experience with this, so I'm open to suggestions and less clunky code.

Comment: Unless you're saving the data into a database, you should be able to skip the `DataSet/DataTable` altogether - simply read the Excel file and transform it into the XML you want.  Can you post a sample of the Excel format?

Comment: Thanks Tim, that does sound a lot easier.. I'm not sure how to include my excel file, so I added a imgur screenshot of it at the very end of my question titled My Excel File Screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are three distinct parts.  The first is a group of PO's, so define it like this

```
    Dim protoPurchaseOrders As XElement = <PurchaseOrders>
                                          </PurchaseOrders>
```

The next part is a PO

```
    Dim protoPO As XElement = <PO>
                                  <firstname></firstname>
                                  <lastame></lastame>
                                  <orderdate></orderdate>
                                  <specialinstructions></specialinstructions>
                                  <items></items>
                              </PO>
```

and finally you have the line items that will be added to the items in the PO.

```
    Dim protoitem As XElement = <item>
                                    <description></description>
                                    <QTY></QTY>
                                    <price></price>
                                </item>
```

These prototypes can be used to create what you want.  Here is some code that simulates a group of two PO's with some line items.  **Note that the prototypes are ONLY used in the creation of new xelements**.

```
    Dim orderfile As New XElement(protoPurchaseOrders)
    For x As Integer = 1 To 2 'simulate two customer PO's
        Dim aPO As New XElement(protoPO) 'create a PO and fill in the blanks
        aPO.<firstname>.Value = x.ToString
        aPO.<lastame>.Value = x.ToString
        aPO.<orderdate>.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(x).ToShortDateString
        aPO.<specialinstructions>.Value = "SI " & x.ToString
        For i As Integer = x To 3 'create line items and fill in the blanks
            Dim item As New XElement(protoitem)
            item.<description>.Value = "desc " & i.ToString
            item.<QTY>.Value = i.ToString
            item.<price>.Value = i.ToString("c2")
            aPO.<items>.LastOrDefault.Add(item) 'add item to PO
        Next
        orderfile.Add(aPO) 'add PO to orders
    Next
    'orderfile.Save("path goes here")
```

This adds one level of abstraction(PO) that wasn't in the 'what you want', but I think it is needed.

The output from the above is

```
<PurchaseOrders>
  <PO>
    <firstname>1</firstname>
    <lastame>1</lastame>
    <orderdate>1/30/2016</orderdate>
    <specialinstructions>SI 1</specialinstructions>
    <items>
      <item>
        <description>desc 1</description>
        <QTY>1</QTY>
        <price>$1.00</price>
      </item>
      <item>
        <description>desc 2</description>
        <QTY>2</QTY>
        <price>$2.00</price>
      </item>
      <item>
        <description>desc 3</description>
        <QTY>3</QTY>
        <price>$3.00</price>
      </item>
    </items>
  </PO>
  <PO>
    <firstname>2</firstname>
    <lastame>2</lastame>
    <orderdate>1/31/2016</orderdate>
    <specialinstructions>SI 2</specialinstructions>
    <items>
      <item>
        <description>desc 2</description>
        <QTY>2</QTY>
        <price>$2.00</price>
      </item>
      <item>
        <description>desc 3</description>
        <QTY>3</QTY>
        <price>$3.00</price>
      </item>
    </items>
  </PO>
</PurchaseOrders>
```

Comment: I've never used Xelement .. does this work from an openfiledialog? I found this link: [MSDN: How to Load XML from file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384609.aspx)

Would that link be related for how to accomplish this?

Comment: This was helpful to at least put me in the right direction. I'll post my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can almost do this with a Dataset by creating a child DataTable and using a nested DataRelation to link them (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sfkwf9s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for details of nested DataRelations). However, you would have to process the 'flat' Excel data to fit the new structure and you'd need a primary key to link the child table to the parent (and this could affect the XML output).

Probably best to use the dataset to load the Excel sheet for processing and then produce the XML programmatically (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387068%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I had to figure out how to use Xdocument and Xelement to make dbasnett's solution work and make some other tweaks to get the xml in the correct format I needed, so here's my final solution. Thanks everyone for your replies.

```
Dim xQuery As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From i In xEleDoc.Elements() Select i
        For Each i As XElement In xQuery.Elements("FirstName") 'simulate customer PO
           Dim aPO As New XElement(customerInfo) 'create a PO and fill in the values
            aPO.<FirstName>.Value = xQuery.Elements("FirstName").Value
            aPO.<LastName>.Value = xQuery.Elements("LastName").Value
            aPO.<OrderDate>.Value = Date.Parse(xQuery.Elements("OrderDate").Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            aPO.<SpecialInstructions>.Value = xQuery.Elements("SpecialInstructions").Value
            For Each line In xQuery 'create line items and fill in the values
                Dim item As New XElement(itemsOrdered)
                item.<ItemDescription>.Value = line.Elements("ItemDescription").Value
                item.<QTY>.Value = line.Elements("QTY").Value
                item.<Price>.Value = line.Elements().Last.Value
                aPO.<LineItems>.LastOrDefault.Add(item) 'add item to PO
            Next
            orderfile.Add(aPO) 'add created POs to orderfile
        Next
```