# VB.Net Save Separate XML Files Simultaneously and Overwrite Data

Tags: xml, vb.net

This question is a continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077356/vb-net-dataset-to-xml-purchase-order/).
Basically, the application let's the user do the following:

- Select 1 or many excel files found on their computer
- The file(s) are then converted to xml and saved.

The problem I'm having now is, I've figured out how to save multiple files, but each file that is saved isn't deleting the old data.

How do I delete or overwrite the old xml data?

**Example of Problem:**

> The app saves 3 successfully converted files titled: xml1.xml,
>   xml2.xml, and xml3.xml
>
> - xml1 has only the data from the first excel workbook
> - xml2 has both data from excel workbook 1 and workbook 2
> - xml3 has data from all 3 workbooks
>
> Each xml file should only have data from the excel file it's currently
>   reading. So, xml1 would have the first file, xml2 the second, and so
>   on.

I've tried clearing, flushing, and disposing of the dataset, xmlreader, and
memorystream after each file is read, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Most of my code is below:

```
'Load Excel File Button
            Private Sub loadFileBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loadFileBtn.Click
                'choose excel file
                'file dialog box properties
                OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls, * .xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx"
                OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
                OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\desktop\"
                Dim checkOpenDialog As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
                If (checkOpenDialog = DialogResult.Cancel) Then
                ElseIf (checkOpenDialog = DialogResult.None) Then
                ElseIf checkOpenDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                    For Each fileCount In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
                        Try
                            Dim countBW As Integer
                            While countBW < OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Count
                                Dim worker As New BackgroundWorker()
                                AddHandler worker.DoWork, New DoWorkEventHandler(AddressOf worker_DoWork)
                                worker.RunWorkerAsync(countBW)
                                countBW += 1
                            End While
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                        End Try
                    Next fileCount
                End If
            End Sub
    Private Sub worker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
            myFilePath = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            For Each excelFile In myFilePath
                For loadedPercent = 0 To 100
                    formLbl.Text = loadedPercent
                    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(loadedPercent)
                    Thread.Sleep(200)
                    formLbl.Refresh()
                Next
                excelConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;""")
                excelConn.Open()
                myAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConn)
                myAdapter.Fill(myDS)
                excelConn.Close()
                myAdapter.Dispose()
                '<----- CREATE XML --------------->
                ''create memorystream that will store xml from dataset 
                Dim xMemStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                myDS.WriteXml(xMemStream)
                myDS.Clear()
                myDS.Dispose()
                xMemStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                ''create xmlreader that will read xml from memorystram into xdocument/xelement
                Dim xReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xMemStream)
                xEleDoc = XElement.Load(xReader)
                xReader.Close()
                xReader.Dispose()
                xMemStream.Close()
                xMemStream.Flush()
                '<---- MANIPULATE XML -->
               'all the xml stuff from my last question goes here
Dim tmpQuery As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From i In xDoc.Elements() Select i
            xQuery = tmpQuery
            xDoc = New XDocument(New XDeclaration("1.0", "ASCII", "yes"), orderfile)
            Dim tmpXDoc As XElement = XElement.Parse(xDoc.ToString)
            'change empty tags to shorthand
            newXdoc = ShorthandEmpty(tmpXDoc)
            'add encoding / declaration
            xDoc = New XDocument(New XDeclaration("1.0", "ASCII", "yes"), newXdoc)
            countFiles += 1
            xDoc.Save("C:\desktop\xml" & countFiles & ".xml")
        Next excelFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some toying around to figure this out. In order to clear the *old xml data* and then save the new data for each file, that meant figuring out how to clear/overwrite the data in my [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077356/vb-net-dataset-to-xml-purchase-order/).

This didn't click until today, when I realized that the old data was actually stored in an xElement called orderfile. A simple 1 line of code is all that was necessary once I knew what I needed to clear.

Solution:

```
orderfile.RemoveAll()
```